# How to connect Sanity to React Native

Tags: r, reactjs, react-native, expo, sanity

I have been trying for ages to make Sanity work with React Native and It's not working out, read multiple documentations, followed many tutorials but no luck.... What am i doing wrong?

Made a simple recreation here:
https://snack.expo.dev/@spts/smelly-candies

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, or what I have to do to make it work

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong here, first I'll assume you meant Sanity and not Strapi:

1. Data isn't loading from Sanity because you need to enable CORS for the expo playground: see more details [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/cors)
2. Make sure you set an [`apiVersion`](https://www.sanity.io/docs/api-versioning#0e5d3c81ce07) in `sanity.js`
3. There were a few issues with your React code which I've updated below, and *should* work once the CORS issue is resolved.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


import sanityClient from './sanity.js'


export default function App() {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const query = '*[_type == "post"] { title, content, emojiType }';
      const data = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

      setStuff(data)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text >
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>

      <Text>{JSON.stringify(stuff)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes Sorry, I mean Sanity (Switched mid project and keep making the mistake)

I ran the code with the CORS enabled but all I get in my text area is []   I must be doing something wrong still?

I want the title that I request from Sanity to show up in the Text Box?